# Yield statement in a using block from a clarity point of view

Tags: c#, .net, iterator

I want an opinion of the community about readability and maintainability of the following code.
This is quite a rare case when yield statement included in a using construction.

I know that this code will work as intended and dispose will be called eventually.
But I'm worried it might be difficult for other developers to understand and reuse it.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string sql = @"SELECT lead  FROM teams";

            using (var sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                sqlCnn.Open();

                using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn))
                {
                    adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        var login = row[0].ToString();
                        yield return login;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If other developers can't understand it then they should improve thier skills and learn something new. Programming things differently because you are afraid someone might not understand it is a no-go for me... I worked once for a company where you should have avoid events because not everyone knew how to use them lol.

Comment: While you would be correct to not code for the lowest common denominator you should also be careful not to write code that is hard to understand. There is a difference between not being skilled enough to understand something and something being obfuscated or written strangely. I would argue that implicitly tying the lifetime of a connection to this method would violate POLA because I can no longer use the parent object after calling this method (as the connection has been closed); you may be interested in [Rx.Using](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Using)

Comment: The `DataSet` needs also to be disposed.

Comment: Just curious, why use "yield" here at all?  What advantage does it give you to just returning a List<string>?  Also, you can replace your "foreach" loop with this one-liner: `return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(s => s[0] as string)`

Comment: @user2023861 for me, advantage is not to make unnecessary object 'List' and superfluous operations with it. Bwt, I like you linq remark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
> {
>     using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
>     {
>         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>         string sql = @"SELECT lead  FROM teams";
>
>         using (var sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
>         {
>             sqlCnn.Open();
>
>             using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn))
>             {
>                 adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
>                 adapter.Fill(ds);
>
>                 foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
>                 {
>                     var login = row[0].ToString();
>                     yield return login;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Usually you shouldn't worry about having a `yield return` inside a `using` block but this isn't needed here at all. This is because the `DataSet` is [disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958179/2655508) from the database. The only thing you would buy would be that for an exception the `SqlDataAdapter`, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` will be properly disposed if for instance the `row[0]` contains `DBNull`.

I would extract the `foreach` loop over the `Rows` out of the `using` blocks which I would also use different. The most outer one should enclose the `SqlConnection` followed by the `SqlCommand` and the last should be the `SqlDataAdapter`.

By stacking the `using` blocks you reduce the horizontal spacing which makes it easier to read.

Because you are only interested in one `DataTable` you should use the overloaded `adapter.Fill(DataTable)` method.

Next to mention is that you should declare your variables as near to their usage as possible.

Applying this points will lead to

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    string sql = "SELECT lead FROM teams";

    using (var sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {

        sqlCnn.Open();

        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    }

    using (dataTable)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var login = row[0].ToString();
            yield return login;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit based on @t3chb0t comment

> The data table is being created before the sql connection, if something goes wrong there, using(dataTable) will not be executed

nevertheless I am not sure it is needed.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
{

    string sql = "SELECT lead FROM teams";

    using (var sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
    {

        sqlCnn.Open();

        adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        sqlCnn.Close();

        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            var login = row[0].ToString();
            yield return login;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DataTable` won't be disposed when an exception occurs. One more using won't do any harm ;-)

Comment: This is still wrong ;-] The data table is being created before the sql connection, if something goes wrong there, `using(dataTable)` will not be executed.

Comment: But if the `Fill(DataTable)` goes wrong then there is nothing to "really" dispose. No data where added and usually there shouldn't any `MarshalByValueComponent` resources needs to be disposed.

Comment: IMHO `using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())` should be the first `using`, and the ones for `sqlCnn`, `sqlCmd` and `adapter` should be closed much earlier: the ones for `sqlCmd` and `adapter` after `adapter.Fill(dataTable);`, and `sqlCnn` after `sqlCnn.Close();`. However, why bother with a `DataTable` when retrieving a single value; [use `ExecuteScalar()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18086686/648075).

Comment: @BCdotWEB - the query returns a list of string values, `ExecuteScalar()` is't  suitable

Comment: @Appolina Ah yes, my bad, forgot about the yield.

Comment: If you move the `using` for the `DataTable` to an outer scope wrapping the rest of the method, you could have the using statements for the SQL objects close before you start your loop (like in your first suggestion).

Answer (score 4):

The true is that netiher the `SqlDataAdapter` nor the `DataSet` nor the `DataTable` are necessary if you use a `SqlDataReader` instead:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
{
    string sql = "SELECT lead FROM teams";

    using (var sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlCnn))
    {
        sqlCnn.Open();

        using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            const int loginColumn = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var login = reader.GetString(loginColumn);
                yield return login;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

- it is also not necessary to close the connection explicitly because it will be closed on dispose anyway
- shouldn't the method's name be `GetTeamLogins`?

Comment: shouldn't the method's name be `GetTeamLogins` - agree

Comment: You should use `reader.Read()` rather than `reader.NextResult()`.  The latter navigates to the next result set in a multi-result query/procedure.

Comment: @DanLyons thx, corrected.